# MAUI/MudBlazor/MVVM Toolkit: Observable properties not updating UI

Tags: c#, mvvm, blazor, maui

I am experimenting with creating MAUI Blazor app using MudBlazor (v6.0.13) components in an MVVM pattern using Microsoft.CommunityToolkit.Mvvm (v8.0.0) and I am confused by the behavior I am seeing in that the UI is not updating when an observable property is updated.

I eliminated MAUI out of the equation and just created a plain Blazor WASM app and the behavior is the same.  But, now I don't know if this is an issue with the MVVM toolkit, MudBlazor, or just the way I understand how the RelayCommand operates relative to observable objects.   I couldn't find any information on if this is an issue or expected behavior.    Can someone shed some light here?

In the MudBlazor sample app I created, it has two buttons, both run the same function `Test` which adds an item to the displayed list of items via an `ObservableProperty`.   One button uses `OnClick` and runs the function, the other uses `Command`.

OnClick updates the UI when each item is added, but Command does not, yet the property is Observable.   If you press the Command button several times and then press the OnClick button, it displays the list with both sets of items added.

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"
@inject ViewModels.TestViewModel vm

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Hello, world!</MudText>
<MudText Class="mb-8">Welcome to your new app, powered by MudBlazor!</MudText>
<MudAlert Severity="Severity.Normal">You can find documentation and examples on our website here: <MudLink Href="https://mudblazor.com" Typo="Typo.body2" Color="Color.Inherit"><b>www.mudblazor.com</b></MudLink></MudAlert>

<ul>
    @foreach (string item in vm.Items)
    {
        <li>@item</li>
    }
</ul>

<MudButton Command="@vm.RebuildCommand" >Test via Command</MudButton>
<MudButton OnClick="@OnClickRebuild">Test via OnClick</MudButton>

@code {

    public void OnClickRebuild()
    {
        vm.Test("OnClick");
    }
}
```

**TestViewModel.cs**

```
using static MudBlazor.CategoryTypes;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace MudBlazorMVVM.ViewModels;

public partial class TestViewModel : ObservableObject
{
//  Doesn't work
//    [ObservableProperty]
//    private List<string> _items = new();

//  Doesn't work
//    public ObservableCollection<string> Items = new();

//  Also doesn't work
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items { get; set; } = new();

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task Rebuild()
    {
//      Tested on another thread for giggles...doesn't change
//        await Task.Run(() => { Test("RelayCommand"); });

        Test("RelayCommand");
    }

    public void Test(string source)
    {
        Items.Add("Item: " + Items.Count + "  (from " + source + ")");
    }
}
```

**Edit**

For completeness, below is **Program.cs** code where TestViewModel singleton was added for DI.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using MudBlazorMVVM;
using MudBlazorMVVM.ViewModels;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddSingleton<TestViewModel>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddMudServices();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Edit #2: Adjusted code to show ObservableCollection use

Comment: Use ObservableCollection instead of List

Comment: Also, don't update from a background thread. UI updates should be done in the UI thread.

Comment: I converted it from (originally) a string to a list to test if the code was running on button click, but it doesn't matter whether it is ObservableProperty List or ObservableCollection, they both behave the same way.   (I tested it).    Yeah, and the background thread for UI...I was messing with that too to see if there was any impact or not.   Nothing changes.

Comment: a List does not fire a `CollectionChanged` event when an item is added.  `ObservableCollection` does.  Using `ObservableProperty` will not cause a `CollectionChanged` event either

Comment: **1)** Edit the code to show exactly what it looked like, when you used `ObservableCollection`. **2)** Find out if code is running on UI thread (MainThread). `bool isMainThread = MainThread.IsMainThread;` as first line of `void Test...`. Is it true? [HINT: It won't be, because code is run inside `Task.Run`.]

Comment: I think we are getting caught up in semantics.  1)  ObservableCollection or ObservableProperty work properly when called from OnClick, but don't in Command.    Why would the behavior be different?     2) Ignore Task.Run(), it was just an attempt to see if there was an impact.    I updated the code as requested using ObservableCollection to show what I tried with that doesn't work.

Comment: Where is `RebuildCommand` in the VM I see only `Rebuild`?

Comment: `[RelayCommand]` generates it.

Comment: Hey! I'm having the exact same problem. Have you solved it?